# Make button enable in html5 from imacro

Tags: html, imacros

The button gets disable after one click and to click again i have to refresh the page. This is the html code to the button

```
/*<button class="btn btn-large center-block btnvote vote" id="765" disabled="disabled">Vote for me</button>*/
```

I want to make the button enable by using imacro by deleting this `disabled="disabled"` and click again by using macro.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

using javascript you can remove the disabled property:

```
document.getElementById('765').disabled = false;
```

you may need to have a quick search on how to run javascript in imacro if you don't already know how to do this.